# Chi-Squared Test of Homogeneity

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, independence

Consider the table below that gives the proportions of a sample from each of two populations that fall into one of three categories (table edited after @whuber comment).

```
                            1   2   3   **4**
First Population Sampled  13% 19% 28% **40%**
Second Population Sampled 7%  11% 22% **60%**
```

Test the hypothesis that the population proportions are equal with a column (category) by calculating the p-value of the $\chi^2$ test statistic. Test assuming the size of the sample selected from each population that gave the above proportions was 100 people at level 0.10.

**Answer**: I have established the following hypotheses:

By the statement of the problem, I am assuming that this is a test for homogeneity. So the hypotheses would be:

1. $H_0:$ The populations are homogeneous with respect to the three categories. That is, $p_{1j} = p_{2j}$ for $j = 1, 2, 3$.
2. $H_a:$ The populations are not homogeneous with respect to the three categories.

However, I then realized that the row totals do not sum to 1, which has me concerned.

Is the homogeneity approach correct? I thought it may be a test of independence, but there are two populations.

Based on the comment below, the observed counts are:

```
                            1   2   3   4
First Population Sampled   13  19  28  40
Second Population Sampled   7  11  22  60
```

So we can proceed with the homogeneity test with $n = 200$.

Comment: Hint: there's an invisible fourth column that you can (easily) recreate from the information given you.

Comment: Since each row must sum to 1 = 100%, I should created the fourth column as in my Edit to my post, and then am able to proceed with a test of homogeneity?

Comment: You are given that each sample was 100 people, so just use that to recreate a table of counts!

Comment: Understood. So this now matches a homogeneity test with $n = 200$.

Comment: You can now answer your Q yourself! Please do so, so the Q do not linger on as unresolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Anti-lingering" Comment:**

Your stated contingency table is `TBL` as below:

```
TBL = rbind(c(13,19,28,40), c(7,11,22,60))
TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13   19   28   40
[2,]    7   11   22   60
```

Verifying that both rows sum to $100,$ as stated:

```
rowSums(TBL)
[1] 100 100
```

A chi-squared test in R, shows significant departure
from homogeneity at 5% level with P-value $0.034 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 8.6533, df = 3, p-value = 0.03427
```

The Pearson residuals reveal explicitly that the 2nd
sample showed lower counts for categories 1 and 2
than the first sample, while the first sample showed a
lower count for category 4. [Taken together,
contributions to the chi-squared statistic from these
six cells accounted for almost all of the total
chi-squared statistic of about 8.6.]

```
chisq.test(TBL)$res
           [,1]      [,2] [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.9486833  1.032796  0.6 -1.414214
[2,] -0.9486833 -1.032796 -0.6  1.414214
```

The squares
of the Pearson residuals sum to the significantly large chi-squared statistic.

```
chisq.test(TBL)$res^2
     [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.9 1.066667 0.36    2
[2,]  0.9 1.066667 0.36    2
sum(chisq.test(TBL)$res^2)
[1] 8.653333
```